# Node and Express - Get Request Url

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a Node app that uses Express. In this app I need to get the entire url. For example, if the user visits `http://www.my-example.com/path/to-page`, I need to see `http://www.my-example.com/path/to-page` in my code. Currently, I'm using the following in my code:

`this.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl`

The above approach works. However, I noticed that my app has taken a several millisecond hit as a result of that single line. I'm not sure if its because of string concatenation or the `get` function request. Either way, it just seems like there should be something on the `req` object itself that would just give me the full URL. Is there something and I'm just overlooking it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that "several miliseconds" has next to no effect on the user?

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I agree. But, I'm doing this as an educational task. I just find it hard to believe I can't just grab the URL from the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so you know, a browser doesn't make a request to `http://somedomain.com/somepath`.  Instead, a browser parses off the protocol and the domain.  It then looks up the domain in DNS to get an IP address and then makes a TCP connection to that IP address.  It then uses the desired protocol to send a request on that TCP socket.  Since this is the HTTP protocol here, it will likely be a GET request and the GET request will contain standard HTTP headers and that path name and query parameters (if any) that are being requested.  The GET request itself does not contain the original URL.

Per the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-44), the browser is required to include the "Host" header which tells you what host name was originally asked for.  That's what you are getting with `req.get("host")` and is the way to get the hostname.

So, unless you can change the sender of the request to include a custom header field that contains the full and original URL, you are already doing what you can do for a standard HTTP request to reconstruct a URL representation of this request.

The HTTP request is under no requirement to EVER send the entire original URL.

If you know the protocol and domain ahead of time (many hosts are known to be on a specific domain), then you can just hard-code the domain if you wish:

```
this.url = req.protocol + '://' + "myDomain.com" + req.originalUrl
```

But, this is unlikely to make much of a difference from what you are already doing and what you are already doing is more portable if your code is ever used on a different domain.